# Добавление элементов бинарного дерева в список

Tags: java

Проблема следующая: нужно добавить элементы бинарного дерева в список с помощью обхода inorder. Я написал следующий метод:

```
 public <A> toListInOrder() {
        List<A> ls = new LinkedList<>();

        if (!left.isEmpty() && !right.isEmpty()) {
            ls.addAll(left.toListInOrder());
            ls.add(value);
            ls.addAll(right.toListInOrder());
        }

        return ls;
    }
```

Для чисел: 10, 15, 16, 18, 5, 3, 1, 6 
должен получится список: [1, 3, 5, 6, 10, 15, 16, 18]
Но я получаю список: [5, 10]
Я посмотрел работу кода в дебаггере. Код действительно обходит все узлы дерева, но при этом неправильно добавляет в список. В чём моя ошибка?

Comment: А не проще просто добавить все элементы и потом отсортировать список?

Comment: Нет. Дело в том, что нужно пройти дерево тремя способами inOrder, preOrder и postOrder и тем самым список должен быть отсортирован в зависимости от способа обхода. Я знаю как обходить, но не знаю как правильно рекурсивно добавить элементы в список.

Comment: А если `left.isEmpty()==false`, а `right.isEmpty()==true`?

Comment: Логично. Тогда следовалобы поменять условие на if (!left.isEmpty() || !right.isEmpty()). Но даже если так.... метод обходит дерево, но не добавляет в список...

Comment: На самом деле вам просто нужно if'а, а не один, а `ls.add(value);` вообще вынести за пределы услоувия

Comment: Спасибо. Второй день бился головой об этот кусок кода.